# How do I post data from my GatsbyJS website to Google Sheets using Sheet.Best API?

Tags: reactjs, google-sheets, axios, gatsby, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to connect my Gatsby website's form to Google Sheets using the Sheet.Best API so the user can submit their emails for updates, but when the user submits the button, nothing happens.

Here is the code for my form:

`form.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import axios from 'axios'

function Form() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const objt = { email };

        axios
                .post(
                    'sheet.best connection url',
                    objt 
                )
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                });
    }

    return (
        <HeaderForm>
            <HeaderInput placeholder="Your email" type="email" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
            <HeaderButton type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Updates</HeaderButton>
        </HeaderForm>
    )
}

export default Form;
`
```

Any help is much appreciated - thank you!

Comment: did you try to give your input a value? `value={email}`

Comment: Awesome that worked. I also changed the Google Sheet to allow the spreadsheet to be edited. Thank you for your help! @PixAff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `value={email}` in your input tag.